# How to get build steps that will run on a particular job before build start?

Tags: jenkins-plugins

I am working on a Jenkins plugin that needs to know information about the build steps that are about to run.

I need this information before the jobs actually run.
I was not able to find this info neither on AbstractBuild or BuildListener classes.

Ideally i will use this info inside BuildStepListener but i as i am writing the plugin can collect it on any extension point

```
@Extension
public class MyBuildStepListener extends BuildStepListener{

@Override
public void started(AbstractBuild build, BuildStep bs, BuildListener listener) {
    listener.getLogger().println("Get all build steps here");
}

...

}
```

Answer (score 1):

An `AbstractBuild` just provides information about the current build — you need to get information from the job that this build belongs to.

You can use [`AbstractBuild#getProject()`](http://javadoc.jenkins.io/hudson/model/AbstractBuild.html#getProject()) to do so, and then use [`AbstractProject#getBuilders()`](http://javadoc.jenkins.io/hudson/model/Project.html#getBuilders()) to get the build steps.

Comment: Great.

I was not able to find because getBuilders() is actualy on Project class not AbstractProject.
So the proper code would be

((Project)build.getProject()).getBuilders()